# Como hago para mostrar un texto con PHP al no tener datos obtenidos de un BD

Tags: php

Explico: Tengo una web donde muestra en tabla datos de la BD únicamente del día, al pasar al día siguiente, la tabla de la web, queda vacía, por no tener aun datos ingresados de ese nuevo día. Entonces quiero mostrar un texto `<p id="sin_datos">NO HAY DATOS INGRESADOS EN EL DIA</p>`. Entonces hice lo siguiente, un `SELECT COUNT` para decirme cuantos datos hay. Y mientras hay 0 datos, muestre el texto. Sino que empiece a llenar la tabla.

Lo que intente con PHP es un `if` pero no sé porque no funciona.

If:

```
$contarDatos = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Factlog_Comedor
            where  panelName = 'NQN_RDLS_GER_COMEDOR_PN3517' and fecha BETWEEN CURDATE() and 
CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY";

$resDatos=mysqli_query($conn, $contarDatos);

if($contarDatos == 0) {
    echo '<p id="sin_datos">NO HAY DATOS INGRESADOS EN EL DIA</p>';
```

Intente poniendo true o false, pero tampoco funciona como quiero.

Else:

```
}else {

    $query="SELECT  
            apellido, 
            nombre, 
            tarjeta,
            readerID,
            descripcion,
            fecha,
            ID,
            is_check 
  from Factlog_Comedor
  where  panelName = 'NQN_RDLS_GER_COMEDOR_PN3517' and fecha BETWEEN CURDATE() and CURDATE() + 
  INTERVAL 1 DAY
  order by fecha desc";

 $res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

más abajo de todo esto, tengo los datos metidos en un `while` Como puedo hacer para que funcione esto? no le encuentro la vuelta :/

Comment: $contarDatos == 0??? contarDatos es un string.. vos querias comparar con resDatos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba utilizando la función [**`mysqli_fetch_row`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) para obtener el valor que te devuelve la consulta en un array, luego accedes a ese array (la primera posición) y lo almacenas en una variable, y ya con esto recién haces tu validación, ejemplo:

```
$resDatos=mysqli_query($conn, $contarDatos);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($resDatos);
$count = $row[0];

if($count == 0) {
  //...
} else {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Gracias, no lo tenía muy claro. Llevo con PHP hace 3 meses, y bueno intento darle todos los días, y se aprende siempre algo.